# I am trying to write value to array and find maximum value of array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

How can I assign value to array and find max from array value

```
Sub maxpain()

'name

sym = Sheets("Analysis Ochain").Range("A5").Value

'Column number

ccol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sym & "COI", Sheets(6).Range("1:1"), 0)
pcol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sym & "POI", Sheets(6).Range("1:1"), 0)

'Find last filed cell in respect of column number

last = Sheets(6).Columns(ccol).End(xlDown).Row - 1

'Define array from 2 to last filled cell

Dim accmu(2 To last) As Integer

'Sum of both column and assign value to array

For i = 2 To last
accmu(i) = Sheets(6).Cells(i, ccol).Value + Sheets(6).Cells(i, pcol).Value
Next


'Get maximum value of array 

max = ??????  


End Sub
```

Comment: One recommendation I would give, Load both columns of data into variant arrays themselves: `pcolArray = Sheets(6).Range(Sheets(6).Cells(2,pcol),Sheets(6).Cells(last,pcol)).Value` and loop those instead of the range itself.  It will be quicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `WorksheetFunction.Max` on the array.

```
max = WorksheetFunction.Max(accmu)
```

Also note, you can't `Dim accmu(2 to last) as Integer` - you can't use a variable within the declaration. You need to `ReDim`.

```
Dim accmu() as Integer
Redim accmu(2 to last)
```

**EDIT:** If you want to find which element of the array is the max, just use `Match`.

```
max = WorksheetFunction.Max(accmu)
Debug.Print Application.Match(max, accmu, 0)  <~ returns the element number of max
```

Comment: Haha. @ScottCraner see my latest activity. I hate one-liner answers but seems like that's mostly what's needed these days.

Comment: Dim accmu(2 To last) As Integer    -also showing error sir.

Comment: Sir can we find in which array the max value is stored. I mean the array number?

Comment: You can use `WorksheetFunction.Match` for that.